# Very huge IN clause in SQL expression

Tags: sql, sqlperformance

Let's suppose i have a product table with 1 million records (yes, i have 1 million products !).

This product table has a reference string field.

Some people wants to export a csv file of all product excepting some products.

We know the references of the product to exclude. They are stored in a csv file.

Here is the query i've built:

```
SELECT ... FROM products WHERE reference NOT IN ('ref1','ref2','.....')
```

Everything works fine with less than 100 references to exclude.

What should i do if i have more than 10000 references to exclude ? The sql query is very big.

I have tried with mysql, postgre and sql server. It's the same problem.

Thanks

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Someone with your reputation should know to tag the question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: If you're using SQL Server, use a table variable. You may well want to use a `NOT EXISTS` too, as `NOT IN` does not handle `NULL` values as people expect (despite it being documented).

Comment: For oracle for example you are limited to 1000 records in an in clause. So you can do NOT IN (......1000 records here) OR NOT IN (..... 1000 more records)

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Do you mean `AND NOT IN` @VeselinDavidov ? Otherwise one of those `OR` clauses is going to evaluate to true. `WHERE 1 NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5) OR 1 NOT IN (6,7,8,9,0)` is true.

Comment: yeah I meant AND :) sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use table value parameters on SQL Server.

The query would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM products AS P
LEFT JOIN @exludedProducts AS EP ON EP.reference = P.reference
WHERE P.reference IS NULL
```

You'll need to declare the table value type like (check the type to match your table):

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ProductReferenceTvp AS TABLE 
(
    reference VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)
```

And your .Net code might look like:

```
public void GetProducts(IEnumerable<string> excludedProducts)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            
    sb.AppendLine(" SELECT * ");
    sb.AppendLine(" FROM products AS P ");
    sb.AppendLine(" LEFT JOIN @exludedProducts AS EP ON EP.reference = P.reference ");
    sb.AppendLine(" WHERE P.reference IS NULL ");
            
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), cn))
        {
            var pExcludedProducts = GetTvp("@exludedProducts", excludedProducts.Distinct());
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pExcludedProducts);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
            Print(ds);
        }
    }
}

private SqlParameter GetTvp(string name, IEnumerable<string> excludedProducts)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("reference", typeof(String));
    foreach (var product in excludedProducts)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(product);
    }
    var p = new SqlParameter(name, dt);
    p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    p.TypeName = "dbo.ProductReferenceTvp";
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Load the CSV file into a table, with `reference` as the primary key.

Then use `not exists`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM products p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM csv_table c
                  WHERE c.reference = p.reference
                 );
```

Of course the logic to create the CSV table depends on the database.  However, any databases that can use indexes should be able to optimize this.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i need to create this temporary table and what should i do if i have several users querying at the same time with different data sets ?

Comment: @Bob5421 . . . You can either create separate tables for each user.  Or just have a single table with some user/session identifier and use that as part of the primary key and query.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to make changes to the table; you can have an additional column as exclude (bit field) and update to 1 if needed to be excluded and if not keep as 0.
instead of maintaining a CSV file, store the excluding data in a table and update the main table before running the query.

Then at the time of querying, just use that column as a filter.